# Which is the best data visualization software?

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I´m looking for a data visualization tool that fits better to my needs. I´ve been searching on Internet and there are lot of different softwares but I have kept in mine some of them which I like: Tableau, PowerBI, QlikView or Quadrigram.

The software will be used in an airline and it would have to allow me to export my interactive dashboards to all crews making them able to play a bit. Is this possible? What´s required from their side?

Please, all information you provide will be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. For example: what features do you need, what kind of data must it process / what dashboard support, how much may it cost …

Answer (score 1):

[Bold BI](https://www.boldbi.com) is a Data Visualization tool to consider.

Cloud and On-Premise versions are available and all plans allow for unlimited users so you will be able to give access to all of your employees.

[image]

Note: I work for Syncfusion (the company behind Bold BI).